How do I specify a class variable in mice for 2 level multiple imputation?
I have repeated measures data for some patients.  Each patient is measured 3 times, but data can be missing in each measurement since some patients can be lost to followup or not show up for appointments.
I'd like to impute the missing data using mice.  I understand I need to specify a prediction matrix, and I do this with the following code:
library(mice)
library(ggmice)
library(lme4)

pred <- quickpred(model_data)
pred[c('vit_d', 'ask_score', 'eq_vas'), 'patient'] <- -2

ggmice::plot_pred(pred)

Here, vit_d, ask_score, and eq_vas are the only variables which have missing data.  The patient variable is the class variable, so I set the cells for the aforementioned variables to -2.
Now, when I try to use mice, I get the following error
Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:1:53: unexpected ')'
1: dv._lmer ~ 1+time+ask_score+eq_vas+age+weight_kg+(1|)
                                                        ^

While I can't be certain, it looks like mice is trying to use lmer, but it can't specify a random effect because no random intercept is specified (the (1|) term).
Have I correctly set up the call to mice?  If so, what is wrong?

Here is a completely reproducible example
library(mice)
library(tidyverse)
library(miceadds)
library(ggmice)

model_data <- tibble::tribble(
                  ~patient,             ~time, ~vit_d, ~ask_score, ~eq_vas, ~age,     ~sex, ~ibd_type, ~weight_kg,
                       "1",                 0,     22,         -2,     -20,  -18,   "Male",      "CD",          1,
                       "1", 0.517808219178082,     33,          2,     -25,  -18,   "Male",      "CD",          1,
                       "1",  1.04918032786885,     NA,         NA,      NA,  -18,   "Male",      "CD",          1,
                       "2",                 0,     55,        -15,      41,    8,   "Male",      "CD",         23,
                       "2", 0.482191780821918,     55,        -23,      30,    8,   "Male",      "CD",         23,
                       "2",  1.41803278688525,     50,        -16,      30,    8,   "Male",      "CD",         23,
                       "3",                 0,    107,        -14,      25,   14,   "Male",      "CD",         12,
                       "3",               0.5,     NA,         NA,      NA,   14,   "Male",      "CD",         12,
                       "3",                 1,     NA,         NA,      NA,   14,   "Male",      "CD",         12,
                       "4",                 0,    122,        -19,      38,  -13,   "Male",      "CD",          1,
                       "4", 0.545205479452055,     96,         NA,      NA,  -13,   "Male",      "CD",          1,
                       "4",   1.0327868852459,    121,         NA,      NA,  -13,   "Male",      "CD",          1,
                       "5",                 0,     76,        -15,      25,   -7,   "Male",      "UC",         -2,
                       "5", 0.843835616438356,    104,        -17,      30,   -7,   "Male",      "UC",         -2,
                       "5",   1.3224043715847,     83,        -13,      25,   -7,   "Male",      "UC",         -2,
                       "6",                 0,     89,        -22,       5,   -5, "Female",      "CD",        -25,
                       "6", 0.832876712328767,    103,        -19,      15,   -5, "Female",      "CD",        -25,
                       "6",                 1,     NA,         NA,      NA,   -5, "Female",      "CD",        -25,
                       "7",                 0,     67,        -13,     -40,  -21,   "Male",      "CD",         35,
                       "7", 0.671232876712329,     42,         -4,      20,  -21,   "Male",      "CD",         35,
                       "7",  1.16939890710383,     49,         NA,      NA,  -21,   "Male",      "CD",         35,
                       "8",                 0,     64,        -22,      40,    9, "Female",      "UC",        8.5,
                       "8", 0.575342465753425,     68,        -12,      30,    9, "Female",      "UC",        8.5,
                       "8",  1.09289617486339,     72,         NA,      NA,    9, "Female",      "UC",        8.5,
                       "9",                 0,     77,        -24,      50,   26, "Female",      "CD",        -21,
                       "9", 0.506849315068493,     96,         NA,      NA,   26, "Female",      "CD",        -21,
                       "9",  1.23497267759563,     NA,        -12,      40,   26, "Female",      "CD",        -21,
                      "10",                 0,     76,        -18,      25,  -15, "Female",      "CD",         35,
                      "10", 0.805479452054795,     84,        -11,      25,  -15, "Female",      "CD",         35,
                      "10",  1.07377049180328,     88,         -9,      25,  -15, "Female",      "CD",         35
                  )



pred <- quickpred(model_data)
pred[c('vit_d', 'ask_score', 'eq_vas'), 'patient'] <- -2

ggmice::plot_pred(pred)


imp <- mice(
  model_data, 
  pred=pred, 
  method = '2l.pmm',
  m=10,
  printFlag = FALSE,
  seed=0
)


Please provide a reproducible example. Can you share some data or use a built-in dataset? Can you share your call to mice?

@Axeman Thanks, I've added a MWE.  I found a solution, so I think between my answer and the MWE this should serve future readers well.

I found the problem.
I was passing my patient variable as a string.  mice expects that this should be an integer.  I simply converted the string to an integer using match(patient, unique(patient)) and the imputation worked as expected.
